# Explanation of polkitd Unregistered Authentication Agent

Tags: linux, security

In `/var/log/secure` every time a user logs in or logs out I notice the messages shown below stating `Unregistered and Registered Authentication Agent`. I have not been able to figure out why these messages keep occurring. Any help with understanding why these messages are occurring and/or if it is possible to fix them would be greatly appreciated.

> Aug 25 09:00:40 TEST polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for session /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session18 (system bus name :1.4467, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.utf8) (disconnected from bus)
>
> Aug 25 13:03:19 TEST polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for session /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2 (system bus name :1.43 [/usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.utf8)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Policykit is a system daemon and policykit authentication agent is used to verify identity of the user before executing actions. The messages logged in `/var/log/secure` show that an authentication agent is registered when user logs in and it gets unregistered when user logs out. These messages are harmless and can be safely ignored.

Comment: Ah, so Registered/Unregistered is a verb ... not an adjective. How does one know.

Comment: Then,how to disable this messages in `/var/log/secure`??

Answer (score 1):

### Different service trying to run on the same port

- I encoutered similar error when running newly installed nginx. Turns out that port 80 is being used by apache. Updating the default port fixed the problem

  ```
  local@machine:/$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN 

  local@machine:/$ sudo vim etc/nginx/default

  server 
  {

   listen 86 default_server;
   listen [::]:86 default_server;
   .....
   ..
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem too.
Because the CentOS service depend on multi-user.target for none desktop CentOS 7.2.
so I delete multi-user.target from my .service file.
It had missed.